# Performing 2 seperate .map operations on a mongo query stored in a variable

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this query stored in a variable as follows

```
var recent_Polls = db.Trump_Vs_Biden_V1.aggregate(
  [
    { $match : {"State":state_Val}},
    {$sort:{"Date":-1}},
    {$limit: 5 }
  ]
)
```

and it returns these 5 documents

[Link to  documents returned](https://pastebin.com/iyhmXsL1)

As u can see in each document there is

**"Biden" : 59,
 "Trump" : 32**

I wish to get all of the Biden values into one array  and all the trump values into a seperate array so i can perform mathematical operations on them.

So for example this is the desired output i would like for all the trump values..

```
[
36,
32,
32,
31,
36
 ]
```

and vice versa for biden...

in order to do this i attempted using the .map function.

```
var trump_Nums = recent_Polls.map(function(e2){return e2.Trump})
```

And this worked but when i tried to perform the exact same operation on the biden values

```
recent_Polls.map(function(e2){return e2.Biden})
```

i got an empty array in return..

I was wondering if anybody could think of a fix to this were i could retrieve both the trump and biden values all at once into 2 seperate arrays. That is maybe more efficient..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this on the client side, you might try forEach:

```
var trump_Nums = [];
var biden_Nums = [];
recent_Polls.forEach(function(e2){
                          trump_Nums.push(e2.Trump);
                          biden_Nums.push(e2.Biden)
});
```

To get this from the server, add a $group stage to the aggregation:

```
{$group: {
          _id:null,
          Biden:{$push: "$Biden"},
          Trump:{$push: "$Trump"}
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wqz5wUwnqpp)

If you need the full documents at the same time as the numbers, add a $facet stage to your original aggregation:

```
{$facet: {
          documents:[{$match:{}}],
          numbers: [{$group: {
                              _id:null,
                              Biden:{$push: "$Biden"},
                              Trump:{$push: "$Trump"}
          }}]    
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TUo-yDV7YTn)